# How do you send body with GET api method?

Tags: javascript, react-native, api

I am using apisauce in a react native app. How can I send body with `GET` method?

[image]

```js
const getMissedLesson = async () => {

  const body = {
    termId: "10BEDDF3",
    inactivityMinute: 20
  };
  return await apiClientTicket.get('/v1/support/missedLessonList', null);
};
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use a body with GET requests and many libraries don't allow it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Are you using `fetch`?

Comment: Definitely check out the article mentioned by Tobias. Basically, while GET isn't strictly forbidden from having a body, many libraries aren't written to allow it to have a body and may act weird. Looking at apisauce's documentation specifically, it seems they only allow a body on post, put, and patch. The second parameter of get is will always get turned into query strings instead.

Comment: On my attempts using GET body with fetch it didnt worked

Comment: At the moment you need `body`, convert to a POST method, because it is not recommended to use GET with a body. You can use post with /:id too.

Comment: Okay i understood. Thanks for all answers!